# I have over 130addresses and I have never sent nor received any bitcoin. How is that

Tags: bitcoinj, keypool

How do I know the amount of bitcoins in an address. My addresses are so many and my wallet says that no bitcoins sent. How is this

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin clients generate a number of addresses in advance for backups to remain complete for some amount of future use. E.g. Bitcoin Core creates 100 addresses in advance, I'd expect bitcoinj to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

> New public and private keys are pre-generated and stored in a queue before use.
>
> This pooling feature was added so backups of the wallet would have a
>   certain number of keys that would be used in the future. By default,
>   the number of entries in the queue is 100.
>
> A command line option allows a greater or lesser number of keys to be
>   maintained in the keypool.

In order to increase - decrease this number of keys you could edit your bitcoin.conf file

```
keypool=50
```

Comment: Are the wallets created within btcd? If so, is there a maximum number of wallets that can be created at one time?

Comment: Yes, within bitcoind, what do you mean by at once? the addresses are already generated and stored on your pc.

Comment: my understanding is that there are 100 addresses generated for one wallet. Suppose you have 3 wallets (within bitcoind): Wallet1, Wallet2, Wallet3 and addresses are generated for each wallet. Would there be 3 sets of addresses stored on the PC (one set per wallet) within bitcoind? If so, is there a maximum number of wallets that can be created within bitcoind?